# Plotting with Julia multiple graphs in a loop or function

Tags: plot, julia

I'm using Atom and Julia to plot a good number of graphs.
I have a code like this:

```
function plotnetwork(A)
  for i=1:size(A,3)
    p,t=findn(A[:,:,i]
    graphplot(p,t)
  end
return
end
```

where graphplot is grom PlotRecipes: https://github.com/JuliaPlots/PlotRecipes.jl

I have the following problems: using this code as a function doesn't plot anything (like if the plots where local variables) and even putting this loop in my main only outputs a single plot in a single window.

What I desire is multiple windows with one plot each, I think the command push may be what I need but I didn't find much online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never displayed the plot. Plots are normally displayed on return in the REPL, but since scripts and functions don't have implicit returns, this isn't happening. So add `display(plot(...))`. Or, save the array of plot objects (`push!(ps,plot(...))`) and return the array of plots so you can `plot(ps[i])` for separate windows.

Comment: As the OP is on Atom, I'm not sure there's a way to have multiple plots in the plot pane (thought that would certainly be a useful feature). So probably he/she would need to use the `gui()` command instead (potentially also adding the option `reuse = false` to the plot command) to open new windows: here are the [docs](https://juliaplots.github.io/output/)

Comment: It can capture multiple plots, but then you just have to use the arrows to navigate them, right?

Comment: Have you actually tried the arrows? They never worked on my setup, I don't know if the feature has been implemented already

Comment: I'm usually using the plotly backend which makes multi window free. But I thought the arrows were working, but I'm on the dev branches of all things Juno so it might not match release